# Laravel sharing same session

Tags: laravel, session, virtualhost

I wanna have two or more Laravel Projects in my computer, but when I created the new project with login and passord, the session from this new project affects the old project.

- I tried creating new virtualhost and didn't work

  This the virtualhost that I created

[image]

- I tried creating different port and didn't work, too

How I resolve this question?

I'd like to call simply like http://localhost/project, http://localhost/project1, but they use the same session.

After all this I desire put these same configuration in a server

Thanks

Comment: Set up virtual hosts so each project is served from a different origin. You can google for many examples on how to do this. Virtual hosts are the simple way to solve this.

Comment: Delete the cookie

Comment: But if delete the cookie won't the both applications  stop?

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `config/session.php`, you can change the `cookie` value to change the name of the cookie Laravel uses to store the session ID. Making it unique to each app will allow both to coexist on the same domain name.

Comment: By default (since 5.5 I believe), Laravel uses a slug generated from the app name for session.cookie.  So setting the APP_NAME in your .env is all you should need to do.

Comment: @Devon Ah! That's new and neat. [Right you are!](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.6.21/config/session.php#L125)

Comment: I must to change the key or the APP_NAME or both?

Comment: You can change `config/session.php`'s `cookie` value to something like `app1_session` and `app2_session` in the respective apps.

Comment: I have changed in the file `.env` the key `APP_NAME=MYPROJECT2` but the session expire many fast when I access the other project

Comment: What's your `config/session.php` `cookie` value set to?

Comment: it currently is like `'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE_'.env('APP_NAME' ),
        str_slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),`

Comment: OK, that should have an effect then. What session driver are you using?

Comment: `'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),`

Comment: I don't know why, but I my home this answer works, but it doens't work in my job